# Check if the start and end date entered is between the already start and end date in database

Tags: php, mysql, validation, date, datetime

I am making the booking script for rent a car. User will enter two dates at the time of booking, start date and end date, what i need that it checks that the entered dates are between the dates that are already stored in the Db for that specific car, 
In simple words, if car is booked from 2015-23-08 to 2015-25-08, and user entered the dates between these two its shows an error other wise the order should be placed.

**Issue in code: it always shows me "in between" even i entered different values**

Code:

```
include 'connection.php';
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
// escape variables for security
$fleettype = $_POST['fleettype'];
$fleetname = $_POST['fleetname'];
$fleetclass = $_POST['fleetclass'];
$fleetdescription = $_POST['fleetdescription'];
$fleetprice = $_POST['fleetprice'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$useremail = $_POST['useremail'];
$userphone = $_POST['userphone'];
$sdate = $_POST['sdate'];
$edate = $_POST['edate'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$driver = $_POST['driver'];
$useremail = $_POST['useremail'];
$id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']);
$products = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM fleet WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1 ");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($products))
{ 

         $stime = $row["stime"];
         $etime = $row["etime"];
         }


$entereddate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $stime);
$contractDateBegin = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $sdate);
$contractDateEnd = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $edate);


if ($entereddate >= $contractDateBegin && $entereddate <= $contractDateEnd)
{
 echo "in between";
}

else {
  echo "no";
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to wrap the date in single quotes if the date is help in a variable, so change your `createFromFormat statements like so.

Also the else has to have an `echo "no"` where you just had a `"no"`

```
$entereddate       = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $stime);
$contractDateBegin = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $sdate);
$contractDateEnd   = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $edate);

if ($entereddate >= $contractDateBegin && 
    $entereddate <= $contractDateEnd)
{
    echo "in between";
} else {
    echo "no";
}
```

You might get better results doing this as I am pretty sure you cannot compare DateTime objects like that.

```
$entereddate       = strtotime($stime);
$contractDateBegin = strtotime($sdate);
$contractDateEnd   = strtotime($edate);


if ($entereddate >= $contractDateBegin &&
    $entereddate <= $contractDateEnd)
{
    echo "in between";
} else {
    echo "no";
}
```

Comment: i already tried removing single quote around variables, and i have change to echo "no"  but sill same issue !!

Comment: See my additional suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You can't put single quotes around variables, or it won't interpolate them:

```
$entereddate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', '$stime');
$contractDateBegin = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', '$sdate');
$contractDateEnd = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', '$edate');
```

should just be:

```
$entereddate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $stime);
$contractDateBegin = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $sdate);
$contractDateEnd = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $edate);
```

What is happening is, none of the "dates" you entered are valid - it is seeing if the string `$stime` - which could just as easily be the string `banana`, is a date.  It is not.  So `$entereddate` is set to false.  As is `$contractDateBegin`, and `$contractDateEnd`.

So then, it checks if `false >= false && false <= false`, which it is (`false == false`).  So it will always `echo "in between";`

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0cb5b5fc82598708fdff66d013d041467bb6fd8a

Comment: i removed the single quote but still same issue!!

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0cb5b5fc82598708fdff66d013d041467bb6fd8a - it for sure works, something else is wrong

Comment: i get these three values from here, please see !!
$sdate = $_POST['sdate'];
$edate = $_POST['edate'];
$products = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM fleet WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1 ");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($products))
{ 
               
    $stime = $row["stime"];
    
    }

Comment: so do a `var_dump($entereddate, $contractDateBegin, $contractDateEnd)` and see what data you have.  This is the part of programming where you have to figure it out.

Comment: it gives : bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) in between. please see the code, i have update it now. but when i sue echo on these three, it shows me the correct values :O